# How to use res.send() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, mongoose

I am using mongoose api with a Node.js/Express application. I have a get request on the client side that asks for some data, but for some reason that data never makes it to the client side. What is wrong?

**Snippet of backend**

```
app.get('/up', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    req.user.local.level = 2;
    req.user.save(function(err){
        res.send(req.user.local.level);
    });

});
```

**Snippet of Frontend**

```
function try(){
    var ks=1;
    if(true){
            $.get('/up', function(data){
                ks=data;    
            });
        }
        console.log(ks);
    }
```

The server console displays 2, yet the browser console still displays 1, What  is wrong?

**Edit**

I took your advice but it still wont work. What am i doing wrong?

```
var ks=1;
if(true){
    jQuery.ajax({
         url:    '/up' ,
         async:   false,
         success: function(data) {
                    ks = data;
                    console.log(ks);
                  }

    });
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is on the client.  Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I want to see where the error is.

Comment: @idude The code simply doesn't execute in the same order as it's written. The `$.get()` executes asynchronously or "*in its own time*" separate from the `console.log(ks);`. For a more thorough explanation, see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    console.log(ks);
```

That code runs as soon as you send the request, before the response arrives.

Comment: would you suggest I do console.log(data) in the callback function?

Comment: @idude: Yes; you can't use a response before it arrives.  If you need to return it, use promises.

Comment: Whatever I type in the callback function, seems to be ignored